# Reusing UITableViewCell doesn't work

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I'm using MonoTouch and I have a custom cell view which is not getting reused.

1. I have tried setting the IBUIReuseIdentifier
2. I have tried using string and `NSString` for the `_cellId` type
3. I have tried recreating the project.
4. the funny thing is that I have other custom cells which are working fine but any new ones I create are not getting reused. I'm not really sure where to look next.

Thanks.

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, 
                                         NSIndexPath indexPath)
{           

    UITableViewCell cell =  tableView.DequeueReusableCell(_cellId);
    LibraryItem item = _items[indexPath.Row];
    LibraryCellView cellController = null;

    if (cell == null)
    {
        cellController = new LibraryCellView();
        cell = cellController.Cell; // cellController.Cell;

        cell.Tag = Environment.TickCount;

        _cellControllers[cell.Tag] = cellController;
        Console.WriteLine("Cell New");
    }
    else
    {
        cellController = _cellControllers[cell.Tag];
        Console.WriteLine("Cell Reused");
    }

    cellController.Name = item.Name;
    cellController.Date = item.CreatedDate.ToShortDateString();
    cellController.Shared = item.IsShared ? "Shared":"";
    cellController.Count = item.Count.ToString();
    cellController.ImageCoverId1 = item.CoverPictureId1;    

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: You don't show the code that is actually creating your cell - when you create a new cell are you using _cellId as the identifier?  If you are not then DequeueReusableCell() will never find a matching cell and will  always cause you to create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

*Some notes*

Do you use a controller for each cell?

Then, where did you declare `_cellId`?

Finally, make attention to `cell.Tag = Environment.TickCount;`. `Environment.TickCount` call could cause problems since it could be fast enough to create equal tags.

Said this, I think you don't really need a controller (if you use it) for each cell. You can create a custom class that extends `UITableViewCell` and use it as is. If you use a xib interface, I really suggest to read the post [creating-custom-uitableviewcells-with-monotouch-the-correct-way](http://www.alexyork.net/blog/2011/07/18/creating-custom-uitableviewcells-with-monotouch-the-correct-way/).

Hope it helps.